# Ansible "apt cache update failed" during postgresql repo install

Tags: ansible, repository, apt, postgresql-13

I'm trying to install postgresql on my remote host using Ansible.
I have 2 solutions, but both work only half as I expect them to work/turn out.

**1. Solution one** (using Ansible **[apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html)** module);

```
- name: Get Postgres latest repository release
  become: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main
    state: present
    filename: pgdg.list
```

This option first looks like it's successful on execution, but eventually gives an error (apt cache update failed):

[image: repository failed to fetch: apt cache update failed]

---

**2. Solution two** (use **[shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)** module)

```
- name: Get Postgres latest repository release
  become: yes
  shell: sh -c 'echo "deb  http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

This accomplishes exactly the same (correct me if I'm wrong) and later gives some other exception (No package matching):[image]

So I'm not getting any further with my playbook, any tips?

My play to install postgresql-13 (or 14):

```
- name: Install Postgres dependencies (if not installed)
  become: yes
  apt:
    name: 
    - postgresql-{{ postgres_version }}
    - postgresql-doc-{{ postgres_version }}
    - postgresql-contrib
    - zabbix-sql-scripts
  when:
    - "not 'postgresql-13' in ansible_facts.packages"
    - "not 'postgresql-doc-13' in ansible_facts.packages"
    - "not 'postgresql-contrib' in ansible_facts.packages"
    - "not 'zabbix-sql-scripts' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Repository keys are provided in another play and performs without errors.

This is executed on a host with Ubuntu 20.04LTS, Ansible version 2.9.6, Python version 3.8.10

I have searched for both individual problems but did not find a specific answer that solved my problem.

*If if perform the same as Ansible manually, it all installs fine (commands used):*

```
sudo sh -c ‘echo “deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main” > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list’

wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-13 postgresql-doc-13
```

**Edit:**
Seemed I also had a quote (`"`) missing at the start of my repo link (before *deb https://...*).

I had: `repo: deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main"`

Should be: `"repo: deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it must be said that an Ansible module, such as `apt_repository` is generally preferable to the `shell` module.

However, you have a few mistakes in your approach.

As you can see, `apt_repository` automatically updates the package sources, i.e. the repository key must already exist. You can add the repository key with the `apt_key` module, but you need to have the `gpg` package installed, which you should ensure first.

From this follows:

1. install `gpg`

   ```yaml
   - name: Ensure gpg is installed
     apt:
       name: gpg
   ```
2. add repository key

   ```yaml
   - name: Add repository signing key
     apt_key:
       url: "https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc"
       state: present
   ```
3. add repository source

   ```yaml
   - name: Add postgresql repository
     apt_repository:
       repo: "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ {{ ansible_distribution_release }}-pgdg main"
       state: present
       filename: pgdg
   ```

When using `apt_repository` one of your problems was that you left `$(lsb_release -cs)` unchanged, but this only works via the shell, instead you have to use the variable `ansible_distribution_release` when using Ansible. Also, the `filename` parameter does not need an extension (`.list`), as the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html#parameter-filename) tells you: *"The .list extension will be automatically added."* Your specification creates the file `pgdg.list.list`.

Again, as a whole playbook:

```yaml
- name: Database Server
  hosts: databaseserver
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Ensure gpg is installed
      apt:
        name: gpg

    - name: Add repository signing key
      apt_key:
        url: "https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc"
        state: present

    - name: Add postgresql repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ {{ ansible_distribution_release }}-pgdg main"
        state: present
        filename: pgdg
```

Now you should be able to install the desired packages, if they are provided by the included repository.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation, now I have a better understanding and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what cause your problem: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880142/failed-changed-false-msg-apt-cache-update-failed-when-trying-to)

Before to add the repository you need to:

1. Add the APT Key.
2. Add Repository.
3. Install Packages.